# SignalR MessagePack Polymorphism

Tags: .net-5, asp.net-core-signalr, msgpack, signalrcore

I am implementing a system based on SignalR that will be pushing client events, for message serialization I would want to use MessagePack. When trying to implement the messaging I have run into a problem where SignalR fails to deserialize the messages on the client.

The messages are polymorphic and described with Union attributes, the standard MessagePack Serializer have no problem serializing and deserializing the messages BUT in case of Signal R it fails with error.

The error reported is  **System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid Union data was detected.**

On the client serialization only works when using the actual class, if I try to use the interface or base class then the error appears.

Classes

```
[DataContract()]
[MessagePackObject()]
[Union(0,typeof(EntityChangeEventMessage))]
public abstract class EntityEventMessage : IEntityEventMessage
{         
}

[DataContract()]
[MessagePackObject()]
public class EntityChangeEventMessage : EntityEventMessage
{
    #region PROPERTIES

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets entity id.
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    [Key(1)]
    public int EntityId
    {
        get; set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets event type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This value identifies database operation such as create,delete,update etc.
    /// </remarks>
    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    [Key(2)]
    public int EventType
    {
        get; set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets entity type name.
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    [Key(3)]
    public string EntityType
    {
        get; set;
    }

    #endregion
}

[Union(0,typeof(EntityChangeEventMessage))]
public interface IEntityEventMessage
{

}
```

So this works

connection.On("EntityEvent", (EntityChangeEventMessage d)

This dont work

connection.On("EntityEvent", (IEntityEventMessaged)

So in general it looks like the problem should be in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Protocols.MessagePack library ?
Anyone have implemented such functionality with success ?

Comment: This sound like an issue with how you setup SignalR, and not your data-classes

Comment: I posted similar question in the aspnet repo https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/30096, I think the problem is located here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/d6a287064b64a98f60a5b1d6560ea0608a817d59/src/SignalR/common/Protocols.MessagePack/src/Protocol/MessagePackHubProtocolWorker.cs#L428 , if am not wrong with current implementation of signalr hub protocol its impossible to have polymorphism as the serializer will always use the actual type when serializing thus omitting any union data.

Answer (score 0):

Currently SignalR does not support polymorphism with MessagePack, more info [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/30096).